Internal 404s in headless Vercel app causing server error
This seems like an issue with Vercel, as I cannot reproduce it with my local headless instance. There are occasions when a page is renamed, moved, or deleted in Sitecore and if other pages that link to it are not republished to Edge right away, there will be a time when there is a dead link on the page (to explain that of course there shouldn't be broken internal links on the site, but it can happen). E.g. /about is renamed to /about-us; on another page that has a button linked to /about, until that page is republished, the button will direct to a non-existent url.
When these dead URLs (e.g. https://mysite.com/about) are navigated to directly in the browser, they go to the 404 page as expected, but when navigated to internally they give a 500 error. When I refresh the page, it loads the 404 page. I don't see any errors logged in Vercel, so I'm not sure how to debug.

This is the code for the 404 route
import { ComponentPropsContext, SitecoreContext } from '@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-nextjs';
import { SiteSettingsFactory } from 'lib/multisite/site-settings-factory';
import { SitecorePageProps } from 'lib/page-props';
import { sitecorePagePropsFactory } from 'lib/page-props-factory';
import { GetServerSidePropsContext, GetStaticProps, GetStaticPropsContext } from 'next';
import Layout from 'src/Layout';
import { componentFactory } from 'temp/componentFactory';
import ErrorPage from './_error';

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async (context) => {
  if (!context?.params) {
    // create params if it doesn't exist
    context.params = {};
  }

  if (context?.params) {
    //const activeLanguage = context?.locale?.toLowerCase() ?? 'en';
    const activeLanguage = 'en';
    const url: string | null = await get404PageUrl(activeLanguage);
    if (url && url.length > 0) {
      // redirect all traffic to 404
      if (url == '/404') {
        throw new Error('Sitecore cannot have a page with this path: "/404"');
      }
      context.params['path'] = url;
    }
  }

  const props = (await getPageProps(context)) ?? {};

  return {
    props,
    // Next.js will attempt to re-generate the page:
    // - When a request comes in
    // - At most once every 5 seconds
    revalidate: 600, // In seconds
    notFound: false, // Returns custom 404 page with a status code of 404 when true
  };
};

/**
 * WARNING - read the warning on get404PageUrl()
 */
const Page404 = ({ componentProps, layoutData }: SitecorePageProps): JSX.Element => {
  if (!layoutData?.sitecore?.route) {
    // no route - we're unable to display
    return <ErrorPage />;
  }

  return (
    <ComponentPropsContext value={componentProps}>
      <SitecoreContext componentFactory={componentFactory}>
        <Layout layoutData={layoutData} />
      </SitecoreContext>
    </ComponentPropsContext>
  );
};

async function getPageProps(
  context: GetServerSidePropsContext | GetStaticPropsContext
): Promise<SitecorePageProps | null> {
  try {
    const props = await sitecorePagePropsFactory.create(context);
    return props;
  } catch {}
  return null;
}

/**
 * WARNING - the Sitecore 404 page's path cannot be /404
 * Builds will break if Sitecore and Next.js are both configured for the path /404
 * @returns
 */
async function get404PageUrl(language: string): Promise<string | null> {
  try {
    const siteSettings = await new SiteSettingsFactory().getSiteSettings(language);
    return siteSettings?.error404Page ?? null;
  } catch {
    return null;
  }
}

export default Page404;

